# removing hidden spaces in perso-arabic string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

i have a string `بشكه` which has 4 characters
when i do mb_strlen the result is 5 which means there is a hidden char in there

i've looped trough its chars to find out whats going on

```
$string  = 'بشكه‌'; 

$string = trim($string);
$string = preg_replace("/\s|&nbsp;/",'',$string);

echo ' total length : '.mb_strlen( $string , "UTF-8" ) ;
echo '<br />';

 for( $i = 0; $i < mb_strlen( $string , "UTF-8" ); $i++ ) {
    $char_b = mb_substr( $string , $i, 1 , "UTF-8");
    echo $i . ' -> '.$char_b ;
   var_dump($char_b );
   echo '<br />';
}
```

here is the output

```
total length : 5
0 -> ب

string 'ب' (length=2)


1 -> ش

string 'ش' (length=2)


2 -> ك

string 'ك' (length=2)


3 -> ه

string 'ه' (length=2)


4 -> ‌

string '‌' (length=3)
```

i've used common function like trim or preg_replace("/\s| /",'',$string)on it , it didn't work

is there anyway to find out more about these hidden characters like what they really are and how can i remove them ?

Comment: `<=` -> `<` If you access the string as array it's 0 based indexed

Comment: @Rizier123 sorry i've corrected that

Comment: You have a hidden character at the end of your string. Just retype it or remove the character.

Comment: @Rizier123 the string is dynamic and its coming from database  i cant just remove last char !

Comment: Then you could remove everything expect what you want to keep

Comment: Something like: `$string = preg_replace("/[^\p{L}]/u",'',$string);`

Comment: @Rizier123 this will remove wanted characters , like space between words which i need to keep like if the string is "A B" i want the space between to remain .. problem is hidden characters

Comment: Yes, I missed that. `\p{L}` doesn't include space. I updated my answer and just added `\h` for horizontal spaces.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know what you need to remove, just reverse it and remove everything except what you want to keep, e.g.

```
$string = preg_replace("/[^\p{L}[:space:]]/u",'',$string);
```

- [**u**](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) modifier for to match unicode
- [**\p{L}**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) character class for unicode words
- [**[:space:]**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) for spaces

Comment: problem is  , this will remove wanted characters , like space between words which i need to keep like if the string is "A B" i want the space between to remain .. i want hidden characters to be removed only

Comment: thanx , this works great ... what if i want to add numbers and/or some custom char to regex like `-` , `_` ,`:`  , you know things that might be in a string

Comment: @SamMir Just include them in the character class `[_.!$...]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex to capture utf8 words :

`$string = 'بشكه‌';
$string = preg_match('/\p{L}+/u', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches[0]);`

Comment: this will remove wanted characters , like space between words which i need to keep